# User input to read file and test that its worked? In C

Tags: c, printf, user-input, scanf, fopen

So I'm probably being really stupid and missing something super obvious but I'm new to coding so I'm not quite sure howto do this. I would like the user to input a file name and an error message to be displayed if unsuccessful. This is what I have so far:

```
char filename;
//declares variable for input.

printf("Please input the file name.\n");
//asks user to input the name of file.

scanf("%s\n", &filename);
//allows user to input file name.

FILE*b= fopen(filename, "r");
//opens the file for reading.

if(!b){

    printf("Unable to open the file.\n");
}
//if unable to open the file an error message should be displayed.
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `filename` mus be declared as an array not as a single character: `char filename[sometingLongEnough];` and then it must be `scanf( "%s\n", filename );`

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it not working (state what you got and what you expected)? Is there an error (then specify the error message).

Comment: regarding the line:  `scanf("%s\n", &filename);`   1) as stated elsewhere, filename must be an array of char, not a single char.  2) In C, an array name degrades to the address of the array.   3) the number of chars the user can input must be limited to 1 less than the length of the array. (if char filename[20] then limit user to 19 char (`scanf` appends a NUL char to string) )   4) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure operation successful.  Suggest: `char filename[20]; if( 1 != scanf( " %19s", filename ) ) { //handle error }`

Comment: Matching my comment to ameyCU's answer: `printf("Unable to open the file.\n");` should better be `puts("Unable to open the file.");` or `fputs("Unable to open the file.\n", stdout);`. General rule of thumb: if there is no actual formatting/conversions to do, don't use `printf()`/`scanf()`

Answer (score 1):

```
char filename;
...
scanf("%s\n", &filename);   // Not large enough to store file's name
```

File name will be a string so you need a `char array` or `char pointer` -

```
char filename[20];           // char pointer will also work with memory allocation
if(scanf("%19s\n",filename)!=1){   
 //  error message
 }
```

Or prefer `fgets` instead of it as suggest by @Felix Palmen in comment -

```
if(fgets(filename,20,stdin)){
  //your code
  }
```

Comment: Just a hint to the OP -- `scanf()` is for formatted input (and it's kind of a beast, but, nevermind this now) -- if all you want to do is to read a line of text from standard input, better use `if (fgets(filename, 19, stdin))`. (Not criticizing the answer here, it's good it is close to the original code)

Comment: @FelixPalmen  Yes I agree on that part . And `fgets` should really be used here . Thanks for your response and always welcome to give your opinions :)

Comment: and still I got it wrong, so if OP still cares to read: should be `if (fgets(filename, 20, stdin))`  because `fgets` wants the size of the buffer and already cares for the byte needed for termination.